# Jungledisk and xLetterCaseConflict

Tags: jungledisk

I've been using [Jungledisk desktop edition](https://www.jungledisk.com/personal/desktop/features/) successfully for years now to sync between several Ubuntu and Windows machines, but when I started to use it on a Macbook (OS X 10.6.8, case insensitive drive) I get a *lot* of xLetterCaseConflict errors.

Example:

```
Sync: Skipping remote file "/sync/some.doc"
Warning Details (Jungle Disk Desktop 3.16 Mac Intel)
------------------------
xLetterCaseConflict - A remote filename differs from a local file only by letter case, and you are syncing to a case-insensitive drive.
Exception Code: xLetterCaseConflict (153)
Time: 2/24/12 1:57:24 AM (GMT+1)
Detailed Message: A remote filename differs from a local file only by letter case, and you are syncing to a case-insensitive drive.
Error Location: SyncJob.cpp:657
```

So I'm looking for a "batch" solution to fix these problems.
Anyone has experience with this?

Would this solution work here: http://cloudmyserver.com/index.php/2011/receiving-the-xlettercaseconflict-error/ ?
(Not a Jungledisk site but seems to be the same service)

Comment: Seems like http://cloudmyserver.com/index.php/2011/receiving-the-xlettercaseconflict-error/ did not work :\